# Open Excel file instead of download using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Can anyone please suggest any idea about how to open an Excel file, kindly check below code and let me know how to achieve opening the instead of downloading the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function read()  
{  
     var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();  
     txtFile.open("GET", "C:\Users\user-temp\Downloads\test.xlsx", true);  
     txtFile.onreadystatechange = function()   
     {  
          if (txtFile.readyState === 4)   
          {  
               // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.  
               if (txtFile.status === 200)   
               {  
                    // Makes sure it's found the file.  
                    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = txtFile.responseText;  
               }  
          }  
     }  
     txtFile.send(null)  
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="read();">  
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
   <div id="div">  
   </div>  
</form>
```

Comment: Excel is not a web browser component, so what do you mean by "open",  and what sort of "Excel file", CSV?  some version of XLS, XLSX?

Comment: Hi Jasen,

Thanks for your quick reply, while opening the file i need to always select an first option "Open With" it's should automatically open the file

Comment: You may find this difficult to do for security reasons. Browsers explicitly limit what can be done with external files that are retrieved from the internet to restrict the chance of some malicious code from being executed.

Comment: Hey Jon,

Thanks for your quick response, here the problem is excel file which we trying upload is being password protected, so my logic was while we trying to upload an excel file with password protected the excel file 1)should open using XMLHttpRequest.2) then we need to provide the valid passoword with authentication 3) Finally the file should read, so please correct me if i am wrong, meantime is there any other approach kindly let me know if any plugin or some idea, it's really very helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

in your case you can use following methods
with **google viewer** iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://sifr.in/img/292/1/courseAndroid.xlsx&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

or with **microsoft viewer** iframe:

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://sifr.in/img/292/1/courseAndroid.xlsx'></iframe>
```

or open it in another tab / window with following:

```
<a href="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://sifr.in/img/292/1/courseAndroid.xlsx&embedded=true">Open your excel file</a>
```

credit must also go to
[this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2300749/m-b-parvez-rony)